# How can I manage big excel files with python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am facing some issues in managing very simple tasks on an excel file with python.
The excel file is about 200k rows, around 40 columns and 64 MB.

Running the most basics commands are taking entire minutes to run, such as:

```
import openpyxl
workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook('filename')
sh = workbook['filename']
maxRows = sh.max_row
print(maxRows)
maxCol = sh.max_column
print(maxCol)
```

Should I stop using openpyxl, what am i doing wrong ? (I am still a beginner)

Comment: You can use `read_only` mode if you just want to read the worksheet.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to make a big difference

Comment: Then please paste the full code along with timings.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **pandas** for this. I have processed 600MB xlsx file in pandas with no issues. https://realpython.com/working-with-large-excel-files-in-pandas/

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the file.